# Create a Layer of White Noise and Save as a Transparency file (With Only the White Noise showing)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png, noise

I'm try to create a layer of white noise in Photoshop that I can export as a transparency (png) file to use on a website. There are a couple of other similar questions on here, but they are trying to export a general noise transparency layer as opposed to a layer of white noise (with only the white noise showing).

I'm relatively new to PS and I seem to have wasted nearly a day trying to do this so any help would be super amazing.

Emily

Answer (score 1):

- Create a document with a **Background Contents** = **Transparent**

[image: Transparent]

- Fill the *Layer 1* with White, 100%
- Set the mode to Dissolve
- Set the opacity to <100% (depends the noise quantity)
- Export as a transparent PNG-8 (having just a color and no antialiasing, with an 8-bit transparent PNG the file size is smaller)

[image: Pink]

[image: White]

Answer (score 0):

### Blend Mode Dissolve PNG With Transparency

Adapt this to your needs.

1. Go to File > Generate > File Asset.
2. Create a new layer and name it [white-noise.png](http://#)
3. Create an area with the marquee tool.
4. Fill (G) it with white.
5. Goto your Layers Panel and set the opacity to `5%` and Blend Mode to Dissolve.
6. Now go to the directory you saved your PSD and look for a folder called [white-noise-assets](http://#)

And there you have it. A PNG of white noise with transparency.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### The exported image:

It is there, but because it's only white noise and transparency, you can't see it on the white background.

[image]